# Stata Merging on Lagged Dates

Tags: merge, stata

I have another Stata date question. I have two datasets, one with IDs and Dates. Here is the first dataset:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long ID float Date
104203 18820
104203 18950
104203 19294
104203 20001
104203     .
112589 17083
112589 18684
112589 19291
112589 19292
112589 19312
112589 19752
123712 18565
123712 19207
123712 19270
123712 19303
220348 19230
220348 19278
220348 19861
227642 17065
227642 17079
end
format %td Date
```

The second dataset contains the same IDs and a date that lags the first one by 0-1000 days (but most are within 15 days):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long ID float COMDATE2
112589 17994.756
112589 18686.793
112589  19753.74
112589         .
123712 19303.693
123712         .
123712         .
123712         .
220348 19278.777
220348         .
220348         .
220348         .
227642 17066.824
227642 17079.799
227642 17940.855
227642 17948.822
227642 18735.777
227642 19066.748
227642 20181.797
227642         .
end
format %td COMDATE2
```

I want to `merge` the two files together. I've tried once, but the dates aren't aligning:

```
merge m:m ID using "C:filename",
gen lag = COMDATE2-Date
bys ID: egen minimum_lag=min(lag)
gen Committment=lag if lag==minimum_lag & lag >=1000 
bys ID Date(Committment) : keep if _n==1
```

I'm looking for a way to properly `merge` these two sets so that dates with the smallest lag time align.

Answer (score 0):

`merge m:m` exists but is usually a bad idea, as many threads on Statalist explain.

From your examples, there is no chance of any `merge` being successful, as all the dates in one dataset are integers (daily dates) and all the dates in the other have fractional parts, so a moment's inspection shows that no observations align. There is no concept in `merge` of an approximate or nearest match.

What's the substantive story here? On the face of it you have two kinds of date-times and the appropriate way to join the files is an `append`.

Again, your examples have missing dates and date-times, which cannot `merge` informatively.

Naturally no one can comment on any other variables that might be in either dataset.